# what is the value of resistor used for 4 digit 7 segment 12 pin display?

Tags: arduino, led, current, display, 7segmentdisplay

refer circuit http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-4-digit-7-segment-display/ .Here no any resistor is use is there any need to connect resistor for a b c d e f g .And is there any alternative for large program on above site

Comment: There is always an alternative...

Comment: please give any idea/logic

Comment: Make your own project, with your own program, do a research about driving 7 Segment Displays.

Comment: That instructables page has got a comment section at the bottom.  That's a pretty good place to post to question at.  You can get the insight from the authors of the original tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many things on Instructables, that circuit is completely wrong.

If the display is common cathode then you need resistors on all the anodes.  For common anode you need resistors on all the cathodes.

You calculate the resistor's value the same way as for any normal LED.

Instructables should be deleted from the web, since a lot of the content is downright dangerous.  It's full of idiots thinking they have a clue when they're completely clueless.  It is true: a little knowledge can be a dangerous thing - especially with the projects that do downright stupid things with mains.

Comment: what must be the minimum resistance connected?

Comment: What is the forward voltage and the maximum current of the LEDs in the display?

Comment: I have got it It's 220 ohm